# C# Image from DLL doesn't load

Tags: c#, wpf, image, dll, resources

I'm writing a small API with multiple classes, models, etc. I'm using in a lot of my projects. In this small DLL there's an About.xaml which is an user control. This UC has an image which looks like this:

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/DeBy API;component/Resources/DBLogo200x200.png"/>
```

This image URI refers on an image marked as Resource (not embedded) which is also in a Resources.resx (public).

Then in my application I add this UC to a ContentControl. Everything works. The texts and links that are in the UC are visible. But the image doesn't appear. When I'm debugging it, VS17 also says that the Source property of the Image control is null.

It's pretty much my first time trying to use image resources in a DLL.

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: "DeBy API"? Spaces in names? Check that twice.

Comment: Have you tried to load that ressource from code behind? That will throw a exception, what Xaml won't do :) Atleast it will give u a hint on whats goin on

Comment: @Gusman Spaces don't work? Is there a replacer like %20 in URLs? Or do I have to rename the assembly and remove the space?

Comment: @TobiasTheel Yes I tried that. No exception. Also the image is clearly visible in the UC in the DLL Project.

Comment: `&#x20`, but I would remove the space from the DLL name.

Comment: @Gusman that actually worked. I removed the space from the assembly name and now the Image loads too. Thanks. Can you write this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using spaces in assembly names will cause a lot of troubles like this. You can escape it in the xaml with `&#x20` but it will be always better to rename the DLL and remove the space from it's name to avoid any future problem.

As bwoggie recommended you should take a look at Microsoft's guidelines for naming: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Just to kinda piggyback off of this, here is a link for naming conventions in C# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @bwoogie If you don't mind I'm going to add that link to the answer as it's very useful for it.